# Blazor Server fails Authentication when consuming Same Origin Web API with Windows Authentication only - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor, windows-authentication, unauthorized

I am calling a Web API from a Blazor Server application published on IIS as a IIS Application under the main site with Windows Authentication only on both.
This means the the Same Origin rule is applied.

Although I'm sending a Network Credential with the request, Same Origin policy prevents the Credential from reaching the API and always get a

> "Error: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code
> does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)."

without any meaningful extra information.

The only workaround I found was to enable Anonymous Authentication on the main site which is Ok for the Staging environment but cannot be done on the Production environment.

On the API I need to know where the request is coming from and for that I need to know which user made the request.

**How can I bypass the Same Origin rule and force the credential to go through to the API endpoint?**

Here's what I've done:

On Startup.cs created an instance of HttpClient for Dependency Injection.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    [...]
    if (services.All(x => x.ServiceType != typeof(HttpClient)))
    {
        services.AddScoped(
            s =>
            {
                HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
                {
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = Config.CredentialsCache,
                    PreAuthenticate = true,
                    AllowAutoRedirect = true,
                };
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler, false)
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri(Config.BaseUrl),
                };
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "MEC2SIGRE Dashboard");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = new Uri("http://mec2sigreqa.telecom.pt/Dashboard");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                return httpClient;
            });
    }

    services.AddScoped<MECDashBoardDataService>();
    [...]
}
```

(Based on [Antti K. Koskela's Personal Professional Blog](https://www.koskila.net/httpclient-in-blazor/) proposal.)

And the class:

```
public class MECDashBoardDataService
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public MECDashBoardDataService(HttpClient _httpClient)
    {
        httpClient = _httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<TaskersRow> MECTaskersDataAsync()
    {
        //******** The error is raised here **********//
        return await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<TaskersRow>(string.Concat(Config.BaseUrl, "/api/mec_api/gettaskersdata"));
    }
}
```

I guess it's a relative simple approach.

On the API:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MEC_APIController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("gettaskersdata")]
    [Route("gettaskersdata")]
    public async ValueTask<ActionResult<MECTaskersRow>> GetTaskersData()
    {
        await taskingScoped.InicializeTasking();
        MECTaskersRow MecTR = PushingDashboard.TaskersData;
        MecTR.Message = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name; //Only for testing and prove that the credential doesn't reach this point
        return MecTR;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Connecting OK.";
    }
}
```

On IIS:
[image: Image of IIS Manager]

I've tried:

```
BrowserHttpMessageHandler.DefaultCredentials = FetchCredentialsOption.Include;
```

but couldn't find how to use it. I think it doesn't apply to Blazor Server.

Also tried:

```
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow()
```

but it messes up Blazor!

Also tried with CORS but no luck here either.

Thanks in advance for any help I can get! :-)

Comment: Does [this blog post](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/05/20/aspnet-core-api-allow-cors-requests-from-any-origin-and-with-credentials) help you? What source did you base your code on?

Comment: @JHBonarius, thanks for the edit! :-) I have tried with CORS but I still get the same error.

Comment: @JHBonarius, I am converting a .NET 4 application I wrote a while back and, in the process, trying to learn Blazor and Core. The piece of code that creates the HttpClient in the ConfigureServices on Startup.cs is based on a blog I found (edited the question with the reference).

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm stuck with this exact issue.